# Include iastor.sys into BartPE

Tags: drivers

How can I include iastor.sys into BartPE using PEBuilder?

Answer (score 3):

Sure thing. This is what I'm doing to get the Intel Matrix Storage driver onto BartPE builds:

- Download the appropriate driver from Intel
- Unpack the driver
- Assuming you've installed PEBuilder into the C:\pebuilder3110a folder, make a subfolder "iastor" under "C:\pebuilder3110a\drivers\SCSIAdapter".
- Copy the entire directory containing the "iastor.sys", "iastor.cat", "TXTSETUP.OEM", and others that you unpacked into the "iastor" directory that you created.

Build your BartPE image and the iaStor.sys driver will be included. If you want to double-check, look in the "i386" folder under the PEBuilder destination directory for the "iastor.sys" driver. It will be there after you've done the above and built a new install.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is actually to use nLite to create a custom windows cd/iso and use it in PEBuilder to create your BartPE. nLite allows you, among other things, to include textmode and pnp drivers.

[nLite](http://www.nliteos.com/)